# Blender not displaying objects in the work-space.

Tags: linux, graphics, blender

- Blender 2.68-4
- Linux peppermint os 3
- Toshiba tecra m1 with Trident Cyberblade

Everything seams to work properly, I get fully functional UI, but in the work space there are only points with orientation arrows, they react as if there wore objects but neither objects nor the grid shows up. They appear in the render thou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have zoomed way out from the objects in your scene.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will reset the 3dcursor to the centre and reset the view.

<kbd>.</kbd> on the numeric keypad will zoom into the currently selected object.

Also there is a [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) for blender specific help.

Comment: No, that's not it. It is my first question on stack, I will take it to the blender.stackexchange. Thanks for your help.